# Why Ajax is not giving the desired output?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I want to check the availability of the username in the database while the user is typing in the text field. I have implemented it using java(servlet) but the ajax is not returning the desired output instead of it some unexpected .jsp file is loading when the keyup() event triggered.

**checkUsernameAvailabilty.java**

```
public class checkUsernameAvailability extends HttpServlet {

Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException ,ServletException{

            con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
            String msg;
            msg = "Select*from users where username ="+uname;
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(msg);
        ps.setString(1,uname);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next())
        {
              PrintWriter out= response.getWriter(); 
              response.setContentType("text/html");  
              out.println("<font color = 'red'> Name already Taken</font>");

        }
        else{
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            out.println("<font color ='red'>Available</font>");
        }


        rs.close();
        ps.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       System.out.println("Sql : error");
    }
```

}

**checkusername.html**

```
<body>

    <form action="checkUsernameAvailability">
    username: <input id="input" type="text" name="uname" onkeyup="fun()"/>
    </form>
    <div id="divi">

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        function fun()
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            var uname = document.getElementById("input").value;
            var div = document.getElementById("divi");
            var url = "/availability?uname="+uname;

            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else{
               xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(xmlhttp.readyState===4){
                    div.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }
    </script>


</body>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>checkUsernameAvailability</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.login.checkUsernameAvailability</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>checkUsernameAvailability</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/availability</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

`Helper class`

**ConnectionManager.java**

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    static Connection con = null;
    static String dburl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dealtime";
    static String dbusername = "root";
    static String dbpassword ="root";
    static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

public static Connection getConnection()
{


        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("driver not found");
        }
        try {    
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl,dbusername,dbpassword);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("SQL error");
        }
        return con;
}
```

}

**EDIT**

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <!-- Default Stylesheets -->
    <%@include file="includesPage/_stylesheets.jsp" %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css"  />
```

```
    <%
    if (session.getAttribute("user") == null ){ // THen new user, show join now
        %>
        <jsp:include page="includesPage/_joinNow.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <%
    }else {
        %>
        <jsp:include page="includesPage/_logout.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <%
    }
    %>


<%@include file="includesPage/_search_navigationbar.jsp" %>

<%@include file="includesPage/_facebookJoin.jsp" %>

<div id = "banner">
    <div class="container_16">
        <div class="grid_16" style="padding-left: 20px; " id="slider">  
            <ul id="sliderContent">     
                <!-- Duplicate this code for each image -->             

                <li class="sliderImage" style="display: none; ">

                    <img src="images/banner/b1.png" width="900" height="300" /> 

                    <span class="top" style="display: none; ">

                        <strong>Fountain Pens...</strong>   

                        <br>
                        pens. Available now for you to get your hands on.

                    </span>

                </li>  
                <li class="sliderImage" style="display: none; ">

                    <img src="images/banner/b2.png" width="900" height="300" /> 

                    <span class="top" style="display: none; ">

                        <strong>Books, Diaries...</strong>              

                        <br>Text Books, Single Lines, Double Lines, Red 'n Blue Lines, Fullscape Books

                        Drawing Books, and all the paper you want to write all throughout to learn 

                        Available now at your doorsteps* 



                    </span>

                </li>  

                <li class="sliderImage" style="display: none; ">

                    <img src="images/banner/b5.png" width="900" height="300" /> 

                    <span class="top" style="display: none; ">

                        <strong>Kids Colors...</strong>             

                        <br>Collection of Non-Toxic childrens colors available

                        Let your child learn the art of painting at an early age 

                        by having his hands on the colors available here... 

                    </span>

                </li>  

                <li class="sliderImage" style="display: none; ">

                    <img src="images/banner/b7.jpg" width="900" height="300" /> 

                    <span class="top" style="display: none; ">

                        <strong>Graphic Novels...</strong>              

                        <br>The most amazing titles that you always wanted to get your hands onn.. 

                        Now you have the opportunity to have them all in your personal library.

                        International as well as Indian titles of many authors available

                    </span>

                </li>   



                <li class="sliderImage" style="display: none; ">

                    <img src="images/banner/b6.png" width="900" height="300" /> 

                    <span class="top" style="display: none; ">

                        <strong>Color World...</strong>             

                        <br>A vast variety of different sets of colors including Oil-Pastels,

                        Pencil Colors, Poster Colors, Acrylic Colors and many more...

                    </span>

                </li>   

                <div class="clear sliderImage"></div>  

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container_16">
    <div id = "contents">
        <!-- LeftSide -->
<%
    Connection c = new DB_Conn().getConnection();
    Statement st = c.createStatement();
    String getCategory = "SELECT * FROM  'category'  ";
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(getCategory);

 %>
        <div id="leftside" class="grid_3">
            <div>
                <ul id="leftsideNav">
                    <li><a href="#"><strong>Categories</strong></a></li>

                    <%
                    while (rs.next()){
                        String category = rs.getString ("category_name");
                        %>
                        <li><a href="viewProducts_.jsp"><%= category %></a></li>
                    <%
                    }
                    %>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="adv">
                <h2><br/>This is The Header of an Advertisement</h2>
                <p>We offer Advertisement display here </p>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

    <!-- Middle -->
    <div id="middle"class="grid_13">
        <jsp:include page="includesPage/mainHeaders/topMostViewedProducts_4.jsp"></jsp:include>
    </div>
    <!--The Middle Content Div Closing -->
</div>
<!--The Center Content Div Closing -->

<jsp:include page="includesPage/_footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

Comment: _What_ file do you get? Does it contain any error message? If so you should definitely post that otherwise we'd not be able to help.

Comment: @Thomas Its very unusual to say but i'm getting the complete different file which is in another directory of different application. And no i'm not getting any error message. I updated that file in the question

Comment: Did you debug and check your servlet actually is executed?